# Index Out of Bound of array in vb.net on exporting to another pc

Tags: vb.net

I created a vb.net project for stocks using Access 2007 as the database. The  project was working just fine in my PC but when I exported the project to another PC everything is working just fine except there is an error Message :- Index out of bound of array.

```
Public Sub showresults(ByVal whatisit As String, ByVal sheetnum As Integer)
    dbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(path)
    Dim data_for_excel As New List(Of store_data)
    Dim forselect As New List(Of String)
    whatisit = " status = 'P' "
    Try
        dbConnection.Open()
        sqlString = "SELECT DISTINCT (bf & '$' & gsm & '$' & desc & '$' & size_paper) AS everh from purchased_paper where " & whatisit & ""
        dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbConnection)
        dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        While (dbReader.Read())
            forselect.Add(dbReader("everh"))
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(" ERROR WHILE SELECTING DISTICT " & sqlString & " " & ex.Message)

    End Try
    Label1.Text = forselect.Count
    Dim storagecell As store_data
    Try
        For i = 0 To forselect.Count - 1
            Dim words As String() = forselect.ElementAt(i).Split(New Char() {"$"c})
            sqlString = "SELECT * FROM purchased_paper where bf = " & words(0) & " and gsm = " & words(1) & " and desc = '" & words(2) & "' and size_paper = " & words(3) & "and " & whatisit
            dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbConnection)
            dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

            storagecell = New store_data(words(0), words(1), words(2), words(3))
            While (dbReader.Read())

                If sheetnum = 4 Then
                    storagecell.changedesc(dbReader("status"))
                End If

                storagecell.setWeight(dbReader("weight"))
                storagecell.setrate(dbReader("rate"))
                storagecell.setdateofc(dbReader("dateofc"))
                getcolorfordfont(dbReader("dateofc"))
            End While
            data_for_excel.Add(storagecell)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(" ERROR WHILE SELECTING DISTICT " & sqlString & " " & ex.Message)

    End Try
    Dim val As Integer
    Dim storecell As store_data
    Dim j As Double = 0
    For i = 1 To data_for_excel.Count - 1
        val = data_for_excel.ElementAt(i).getsum
        storecell = data_for_excel.ElementAt(i)
        j = i - 1
        While (j >= 0 And data_for_excel.ElementAt(j).getsum > val)
            data_for_excel.RemoveAt(j + 1)
            data_for_excel.Insert(j + 1, data_for_excel.ElementAt(j))
            j = j - 1
        End While
        data_for_excel.RemoveAt(j + 1)
        data_for_excel.Insert(j + 1, storecell)
    Next
    Dim inn As Integer = data_for_excel.Count



    exlworksheet = exlworkbook.Worksheets(sheetnum)

    If sheetnum = 1 Then
        exlworksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = "IN STOCKS"
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = " Same Month"
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = " 1 Month old "
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 5).Value = " 2 Months old"
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = " 3 Months old"
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 9).Value = " 4 Months old"
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 11).Value = " 5 Months old "
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 13).Value = " 6 or More Months old "

        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 3).Font.color = RGB(0, 100, 255)
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 5).Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 7).Font.color = RGB(125, 0, 125)
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 9).Font.color = RGB(150, 125, 200)
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 11).Font.color = RGB(100, 25, 250)
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 13).Font.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    ElseIf sheetnum = 2 Then
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "CONSUMED IN PERIOD FROM " & TextBox1.Text & " TO " & TextBox2.Text
    ElseIf sheetnum = 3 Then
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "SOLD IN PERIOD FROM " & TextBox1.Text & " TO " & TextBox2.Text
    ElseIf sheetnum = 4 Then
        exlworksheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "SEND FOR JOB WORK IN PERIOD FROM " & TextBox1.Text & " TO " & TextBox2.Text
    End If

    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = " BF / GSM"
    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = " SIZE "
    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = " REEL DETAILS --------------->"
    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 52).Value = "TOTAL WEIGHT "
    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 53).Value = "AVG. RETE"
    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 54).Value = " TOTAL AMOUNT "
    exlworksheet.Cells(3, 55).Value = " SIZE"
    row = 4
    col = 0
    Dim rowcountmax As Integer = data_for_excel.Count
    For index = 0 To data_for_excel.Count - 1
        exlworksheet.Cells(row, col + 1).Value = data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getbdg
        exlworksheet.Cells(row, col + 2).Value = data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getSize
        exlworksheet.Cells(row, col + 53).Value = data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getavgrate
        exlworksheet.Cells(row, col + 55).Value = data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getSize
        exlworksheet.Cells(row, col + 52).Value = "=sum(C" & row.ToString & ":AX" & row.ToString & ")"
        exlworksheet.Cells(row, col + 54).Value = "=AZ" & row.ToString & "*BA" & row.ToString & ""
        Dim arrayofweight As New List(Of Double)
        Dim arrayofdate As New List(Of String)
        col = 3
        arrayofweight = data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getweightarray
        arrayofdate = data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getdateaar
        For ind = 0 To data_for_excel.ElementAt(index).getweinum - 1
            exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Value = arrayofweight.ElementAt(ind)
            Dim forcol As Integer = getcolorfordfont(arrayofdate.ElementAt(ind))

            If sheetnum = 1 Then
                If forcol = 0 Then
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
                ElseIf forcol = 1 Then
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(0, 100, 255)
                ElseIf forcol = 2 Then
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                ElseIf forcol = 3 Then
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(125, 0, 125)
                ElseIf forcol = 4 Then
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(150, 125, 200)
                ElseIf forcol = 5 Then
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(100, 25, 250)
                Else
                    exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            End If


            'exlworksheet.Cells(row, col).Font.color = RGB((getcolorfordfont(arrayofdate.ElementAt(ind) Mod 3)) * 2, (arrayofdate.ElementAt(ind) Mod 5) * 10, (arrayofdate.ElementAt(ind) / 5))
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 0
        row = row + 1
    Next

    rowcountmax = rowcountmax + 1

    dbConnection.Close()
    '  exlworksheet.Cells(rowcountmax, 52).Value = "=sum(AZ4:AZ" & rowcountmax.ToString
    ' exlworksheet.Cells(rowcountmax, 54).Value = "=sum(BB4:BB" & rowcountmax.ToString
    'exlworksheet.Cells(rowcountmax, 53).Value = "=BB" & rowcountmax.ToString & "/AZ" & rowcountmax.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a bad start for your first question - though there is an important piece of information missing -what line does the error happen on? Thanks

Comment: while executing this line 'sqlString = "SELECT * FROM purchased_paper where bf = " & words(0) & " and gsm = " & words(1) & " and desc = '" & words(2) & "' and size_paper = " & words(3) & "and " & whatisit'

Comment: You should verify that there's enough items in words(), the error seems to point that there are to few

Comment: but this same code is working in my pc with same database entries. if error was because of this. then it should not work on either of PCs. right?

Comment: Clearly something is different between the two. The data in the DB on the other PC is not the same as yours. You ought to check the resulting array's length before accessing it.

Comment: No Man !! data on Db is same. and I also changed the Code. but error still presists

Comment: please help me .. I need to submit this project in 3 days Man!!!

Comment: thanks ... i caught my problem. error was due chamge in date formet in both the PCs

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved - Good luck with submitting it.